# KCfinder doesn't work in local development WAMP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wamp, kcfinder

I got an web application which i want to implement KCfinder for Image Upload Management. But it doesn't work in my local wamp server (I got window 7 and have wamp installed on it)

I have tried upload the KCFinder package to my live web hosting, and it work normally

[image: This image is from my live hosting server]
This image is from my live hosting server

[image: This Image is from my local development server]
This Image is from my local development server. (No Directory and those buttons are not working)

Any help would be appreciated, Thank very much

Comment: Have you created a Virtual Hosts to run the site in or are you just using `\wamp\www\folder` and running your site from the browser as `localhost/folder`

Comment: I host on \wamp\www\folder,

Comment: When i used localhost:81/mysite, it is working fine. But when i used 192.168.1.1/mysite, it does not work. (192.168.1.1 is my local ip address). and i configure my wamp to be able to view from any ip in my subnet

Comment: Are you sure about `192.168.1.1` that is normally the ip address of your router?

Comment: I would think that the issue of an empty view is to do with directory paths. Create a Virtual Host for this (and every project) you do locally. This makes the site look like the live site i.e. it has the correct DocumentRoot. [See here for how to setup Virtual Hosts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618)